# Convert IReliableDictionary to IList

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have an IReliableDictionary and need to take the items in the dictionary and move them in to an IList to return from my reliable service.

It seems I can't do a .ToList of any kind, so I'm sure I'm approaching it wrong.

```
public async Task<IList<CustomerOrderItem>> GetOrdersAsync()
{   


   IReliableDictionary<CustomerOrderItemId, CustomerOrderItem> orderItems =
   await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<CustomerOrderItemId, CustomerOrderItem>>(CustomerOrderItemDictionaryName);

   Dictionary<KeyValuePair<CustomerOrderItemId, CustomerOrderItem>, KeyValuePair<CustomerOrderItemId, CustomerOrderItem>> items = orderItems.ToDictionary(v => v);

   IList<CustomerOrderItem> list = orderItems.ToList(); ???

   ...
}
```

Any ideas on how to take the items from the dictionary and put them in to the list?

Comment: You can use an extension that was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877614/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-search-an-ireliabledictionary

Comment: See current workaround in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877614/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-search-an-ireliabledictionary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would be the best way to search an IReliableDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877614/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-search-an-ireliabledictionary)

Answer (score 0):

`IReliableDictionary<K,V>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>`, so you can do a `ToList`.

Maybe ensure the namespace is imported.

Answer (score 0):

IReliableDictionary (just like an IDictionary) is IEnumerable of key value pairs, so you can go this way:

```
public async Task<IList<CustomerOrderItem>> GetOrdersAsync()
    {
        IReliableDictionary<CustomerOrderItemId, CustomerOrderItem> orderItems =
        await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<CustomerOrderItemId, CustomerOrderItem>>(CustomerOrderItemDictionaryName);

        var list = orderItems.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Yes this is the best way to do it if you want a list of the values rather than a list of KeyValuePair. Depending on your usage, you may want to consider changing the return type to IEnumerable and just returning the IEnumerable select result rather than converting to a list to avoid an entire list allocation.