# Linq query on IReliableDictionary

Tags: c#, linq, azure-service-fabric

I have done a bunch of looking and messing with code and I haven't found a way to do Linq Queries against the `IReliableDictionary`. I know it's not the same as standard `IDictionary`, but I was curious if anyone has had any luck. I'm starting to think it's just not possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like MS removed the ability to do linq queries in the latest SF release.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there's no normal way to do a linq query on a reliable dictionary. That being said, there are a few things you can do. As previously stated, the reason the CreateEnumerableAsync method exists is because service fabric pages reliable dictionaries to disk, but if you know that the underlying collection is small and you're okay with a performance hit, then the following class will work.

```
public static class AsyncEnumerableExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the collection to a list
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TValType">value type of the collection</typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumerator">enumerator to convert</param>
    /// <param name="ct">cancellation token for the async operations</param>
    /// <param name="tx">tx to enforce that this is called in a transactional context</param>
    /// <returns>a list containing all elements in the origin collection</returns>
    public static async Task<IList<TValType>> ToListAsync<TValType>(
        this IAsyncEnumerator<TValType> enumerator,CancellationToken ct, ITransaction tx)
    {
        IList<TValType> ret = new List<TValType>();
        while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync(ct).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            ret.Add(enumerator.Current);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the collection to a list
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TValType">value type of the collection</typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumerator">enumerator to convert</param>
    /// <param name="tx">tx to enforce that this is called in a transactional context</param>
    /// <returns>a list containing all elements in the origin collection</returns>
    public static Task<IList<TValType>> ToListAsync<TValType>(
        this IAsyncEnumerator<TValType> enumerator, ITransaction tx)
    {
        return enumerator.ToListAsync(CancellationToken.None,tx);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the collection to a list
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TValType">value type of the collection</typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumerable">enumerator to convert</param>
    /// <param name="ct">cancellation token for the async operations</param>
    /// <param name="tx">tx to enforce that this is called in a transactional context</param>
    /// <returns>a list containing all elements in the origin collection</returns>
    public static Task<IList<TValType>> ToListAsync<TValType>(this IAsyncEnumerable<TValType> enumerable,
        CancellationToken ct, ITransaction tx)
    {
        return enumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator().ToListAsync(ct,tx);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the collection to a list
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TValType">value type of the collection</typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumerable">enumerator to convert</param>
    /// <param name="tx">tx to enforce that this is called in a transactional context</param>
    /// <returns>a list containing all elements in the origin collection</returns>
    public static Task<IList<TValType>> ToListAsync<TValType>(this IAsyncEnumerable<TValType> enumerable, ITransaction tx)
    {
        return enumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator().ToListAsync(tx);
    }
}
```

You could also implement your own custom enumerators and extension methods to perform linq-query like operations on your data in an efficient manner. I have written a few that I would like to release but they need some polish first. I have a sneaking feeling that the service fabric team might already be on it, but if or when that happens your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Thanks! I have this problem too and this was very helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle operations that are more involved than simple `GetByKey()`, you would need to explicitly create a local collection of it via the [`IReliableDictionary.CreateEnumerable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt643798.aspx) method, which you would then be able to query similar to the following example from [the comments in this discussion](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections/#comment-2609456802) :

```
IAsyncEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string="">> enumerable = await myDictionary.CreateEnumerableAsync(tx);
using (IAsyncEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, string="">> e = enumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator())
{
    while (await e.MoveNextAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
         doSomething(e.Current);
    }
}
```

This may not fit your scenario at all, but it seems that it's likely the only way to perform any kind of "advanced queries".

Comment: CreateEnumerableAsync doesn't work either. I've already tried that. It returns IAsyncEnumerator which is not the same as IEnumerable.

Comment: Yeah. Your edit is what I am doing now. Doesn't really solve my issue. I think I'm going to have to approach it differently. Thanks.

Comment: Correct. I added a snippet that I came across in the comments of the [Reliable Collections documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections/) that details how this is handled.

Comment: Sorry that it couldn't be more helpful. Hope that you figure out a way to get this resolved.

Comment: NP. Thanks for giving it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Right LINQ will not work with IAsyncEnumerator

```
var wgEnumerable = await voteDictionary.CreateEnumerableAsync(tx);
using(IAsyncEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, int>> enumerator = wgEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator())
{
while(await enumerator.MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken.None))
{
//Do something
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Async Linq after converting SerivceFabric's `IAsyncEnumerable` to a dotnet one.

Please refer to this answer:
[Convert IReliableDictionary to IList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459822/convert-ireliabledictionary-to-ilist/61848400#61848400)