# What would be the best way to search an IReliableDictionary?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Based on these posts:

[Convert IReliableDictionary to IList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459822/convert-ireliabledictionary-to-ilist?s=1|6.4860)

[What is the most optimal method of querying a reliable dictionary collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174145/what-is-the-most-optimal-method-of-querying-a-reliable-dictionary-collection?s=2|4.1161)

I should be able to use Linq to query an IReliableDictionary, but it would appear that this interface no longer implements IEnumerable and the Linq extensions are not available. At least in version 5.0.0.0 of the Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Interfaces assembly.

If this is true, what would be the best way to search an IReliableDictionary?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, we did remove IEnumerable from Reliable Collections in the GA release. As Allan T mentions, Reliable Collections aren't really the same as regular .NET collections, even though they represent the same fundamental data structures. One of the big differences you've probably noticed is that all operations are asynchronous, because of locking semantics and I/O for replication and disk reads. It's the latter part that drove the decisions to remove IEnumerable, because it is strictly synchronous and we're not. Instead we now use IAsyncEnumerable, which as of yet does not support the full set of LINQ extension methods.

We're working on asynchronous LINQ extension methods, but in the meantime, there are a couple of ways to work with IAsyncEnumerable.

[Eli Arbel has async extension methods on Gist](https://gist.github.com/aelij/987d974c811865029564f1bbeffb6b47) that provide a bridge to [System.Interactive.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/) and also async implementations of Select, SelectMany, and Where.

Or you can [wrap IAsyncEnumerable in a regular IEnumerable](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-management-party-cluster/blob/sdkupdate/PartyCluster/Common/IAsyncEnumerableExtensions.cs) that simply wraps the asynchronous calls with synchronous methods, and that will give you the full set of LINQ extensions methods again. Then you can use the extension method in a regular LINQ query:

```
        using (ITransaction tx = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
        {
            var x = from item in (await clusterDictionary.CreateEnumerableAsync(tx)).ToEnumerable()
                   where item.Value.Status == ClusterStatus.Ready
                   orderby item.Value.CreatedOn descending
                   select new ClusterView(
                       item.Key,
                       item.Value.AppCount,
                       item.Value.ServiceCount,
                       item.Value.Users.Count(),
                       this.config.MaximumUsersPerCluster,
                       this.config.MaximumClusterUptime - (DateTimeOffset.UtcNow - item.Value.CreatedOn.ToUniversalTime()));

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Eli, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the extension! It's very handy/useful. I was able to replace my old code use these extension. It works right away.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the reasoning behind removing LINQ support, I figured this to be the case. The extension and nuget library look promising and I will give them a try. It would be nice if there was an async LINQ implementation in the core libraries as this would be a compelling feature. Is there a timeline for these?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it's the "best" way, but I have been using the following

```
public static async Task<IList<KeyValuePair<Guid, T>>> QueryReliableDictionary<T>(IReliableStateManager stateManager, string collectionName, Func<T, bool> filter)
{
    var result = new List<KeyValuePair<Guid, T>>();

    IReliableDictionary<Guid, T> reliableDictionary =
        await stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<Guid, T>>(collectionName);

    using (ITransaction tx = stateManager.CreateTransaction())
    {
        IAsyncEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid, T>> asyncEnumerable = await reliableDictionary.CreateEnumerableAsync(tx);
        using (IAsyncEnumerator<KeyValuePair<Guid, T>> asyncEnumerator = asyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator())
        {
            while (await asyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken.None))
            {
                if (filter(asyncEnumerator.Current.Value))
                    result.Add(asyncEnumerator.Current);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You use the method by passing in the StateManager, the name of the collection you wish to query and a lambda function with your query logic. For example:

```
var queryResult = await QueryReliableDictionary<string>(this.StateManager, "CustomerCollection", name => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) && (name.IndexOf("fred", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));
```

Comment: I should mention, I have been using Guid's for my dictionary keys. If you need to use a different type, you would need to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: This is almost identical to what I ended up doing, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing this answer, `IAsyncEnumerable` is a part of dotnet libraries, and C# 8.0 adds a syntax sugar to support it.

The problem is ServiceFabric uses its own definition of `IAsyncEnumerable`, so you can not apply dotnet extension methods and C# helpers to it.

A solution I came up with is to convert the ServiceFabric's `IAsyncEnumerable` to the native one using a simple wrapper:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Generic = System.Collections.Generic;
using Fabric = Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data;

public static class FabricAsyncEnumerableExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts ServiceFabric <see cref="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.IAsyncEnumerable"/> to dotnet native <see cref="System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<T> ToGeneric<T>(this Fabric.IAsyncEnumerable<T> source) =>
        new AsyncEnumerableWrapper<T>(source);

    private class AsyncEnumerableWrapper<T> : Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<T>
    {
        private readonly Fabric.IAsyncEnumerable<T> _source;

        public AsyncEnumerableWrapper(Fabric.IAsyncEnumerable<T> source) => _source = source;

        public Generic.IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken _ = default)
        {
            Fabric.IAsyncEnumerator<T> enumerator = _source.GetAsyncEnumerator();
            return new AsyncEnumeratorWrapper<T>(enumerator);
        }
    }

    private class AsyncEnumeratorWrapper<T> : Generic.IAsyncEnumerator<T>
    {
        private readonly Fabric.IAsyncEnumerator<T> _source;

        public AsyncEnumeratorWrapper(Fabric.IAsyncEnumerator<T> source) => _source = source;

        public async ValueTask DisposeAsync() =>
            await Task.Run(_source.Dispose).ConfigureAwait(false);

        public async ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync() =>
            await _source.MoveNextAsync(default).ConfigureAwait(false);

        public T Current => _source.Current;
    }
}
```

Using it becomes as simple as calling the extension method, then using it as a regular `IAsyncEnumerable`:

```
Fabric.IAsyncEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid, Product>> asyncProducts = GetAsyncProducts();
return await asyncProducts.ToGeneric()
    .Select(p => p.Value)
    .ToListAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the service fabric reliable dictionaries may look like a regular .NET dictionary but they are not really the same. So some methods might not be supported in the SF reliable dictionary or queue.

Comment: As recently as October 2015 a senior program manager from MS posted that LINQ was available on this collection (second link above). It would appear that the ability to use LINQ extensions was removed prior to GA of Service fabric.