# Service Fabric - (reaching MaxReplicationMessageSize) Huge amount of data in a reliable dictionary

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

**EDIT** question summary:

- I want to expose an endpoints, that will be capable of returning portions of xml data by some query parameters.
- I have a statefull service (that is keeping the converted to DTOs xml data into a reliable dictionary)
- I use a single, named partition (I just cant tell which partition holds the data by the query parameters passed, so I cant implement some smarter partitioning strategy)
- I am using service remoting for communication between the stateless WEBAPI service and the statefull one
- XML data may reach 500 MB
- Everything is OK when the XML only around 50 MB
- When data gets larger I Service Fabric complaining about MaxReplicationMessageSize

and the summary of my few questions from below: *how can one achieve storing large amount of data into a reliable dictionary?*

TL DR;

Apparently, I am missing something...

- I want to parse, and load into a reliable dictionary huge XMLs for later queries over them.
- I am using a single, named partition.
- I have a XMLData stateful service that is loading this xmls into a reliable dictionary in its RunAsync method via this peace of code:

  ```
  var myDictionary = await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, List<HospitalData>>>("DATA");
      using (var tx = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
      {
          var result = await myDictionary.TryGetValueAsync(tx, "data");

          ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, "data status: {0}",
                  result.HasValue ? "loaded" : "not loaded yet, starts loading");

          if (!result.HasValue)
          {
              Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
              timer.Start();

              var converter = new DataConverter(XmlFolder);
              List <Data> data = converter.LoadData();
              await myDictionary.AddOrUpdateAsync(tx, "data", data, (key, value) => data);

              timer.Stop();
              ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this,
                      string.Format("Loading of data finished in {0} ms",
                      timer.ElapsedMilliseconds));
          }
          await tx.CommitAsync();
      }
  ```
- I have a stateless WebApi service that is communicating with the above stateful one via [service remoting](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting/) and querying the dictionary via this code:

  ```
  ServiceUriBuilder builder = new ServiceUriBuilder(DataServiceName);
  DataService DataServiceClient = ServiceProxy.Create<IDataService>(builder.ToUri(),
      new Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Client.ServicePartitionKey("My.single.named.partition"));
  try
  {
      var data = await DataServiceClient.QueryData(SomeQuery);
      return Ok(data);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      ServiceEventSource.Current.Message("Web Service: Exception: {0}", ex);
      throw;
  }
  ```
- It works really well when the XMLs do not exceeds 50 MB.
- After that I get errors like:

> System.Fabric.FabricReplicationOperationTooLargeException: The replication operation is larger than the configured limit - MaxReplicationMessageSize ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Questions:

- I am almost certain that it is about the partitioning strategy and I need to use more partitions. But how to reference a particular partition while in the context of the RunAsync method of the Stateful Service? (Stateful service, is invoked via the RPC in WebApi where I explicitly point out a partition, so in there I can easily chose among partitions if using the Ranged partitions strategy - but how to do that while the initial loading of data when in the Run Async method)
- Are these thoughts of mine correct: the code in a stateful service is operating on a single partition, thus Loading of huge amount of data and the partitioning of that data should happen outside the stateful service (like in an Actor). Then, after determining the partition key I just invoke the stateful service via RPC and pointing it to this particular partition
- Actually is it at all a partitioning problem and what (where, who) is defining the Size of a Replication Message? I.e is the partiotioning strategy influencing the Replication Message sizes?
- Would excerpting the loading logic into a stateful Actor help in any way?

For any help on this - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to add a large amount of data into a single dictionary record. When Service Fabric tries to replicate that data to other replicas of the service, it encounters a quota of the replicator, `MaxReplicationMessageSize`, which indeed defaults to 50MB (documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicefabric.data.reliablestatemanagerreplicatorsettings.maxreplicationmessagesize.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

You can increase the quota by specifying a `ReliableStateManagerConfiguration`:

```
internal sealed class Stateful1 : StatefulService
{
    public Stateful1(StatefulServiceContext context)
        : base(context, new ReliableStateManager(context,
            new ReliableStateManagerConfiguration(new ReliableStateManagerReplicatorSettings
            {
                MaxReplicationMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 200
            }))) { }
}
```

**But I strongly suggest you change the way you store your data**. The current method won't scale very well and isn't the way Reliable Collections were meant to be used.

Instead, you should store each `HospitalData` in a separate dictionary item. Then you can query the items in the dictionary (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902170/276083) for details on how to use LINQ). You will **not** need to change the above quota.

PS - You don't necessarily have to use partitioning for 500MB of data. But regarding your question - you could use partitions even if you can't derive the key from the query, simply by querying all partitions and then combining the data.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually started thinking to partition the data putting each hospital XML into a separate partition. Now I see its not needed, but rather I can use the same partition's dictionary, but just to put each hospital XML into a separate key in that dictionary. Just out of curiosity- what would be like a best practice if I want to use partitions - how to query all the partitions?I mean - is this done in the context of the stateful service itself,or it should be done outside, in the caller,i.e the caller to get all the partitions,query them one by one etc. Again - thanks a lot!

Comment: O yeah, for sure will ask! :) Will organize my question and  put some code in it. Then will update this comment with a link to it

Comment: heres the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774965/how-to-enumerate-all-partitions-and-aggregate-results) on enumerating all partitions :) : This time decided to leave it as short as possible

Comment: I have a situation where I am attempting to store 120k+ records with child records and am tripping this limit as well. The issue I have is that storing each record individually isn't an option as I need to retrieve them in bulk by a groupId, and a reliable dictionary requires each key to be unique so I can't use the groupId as the key. I looked at the library https://github.com/jessebenson/service-fabric-indexing which attempts to store a separate index in another reliable collection, but then I run into errors when attempting to loop through the 120k records with transactions rolling back.

Comment: It seems the only way I can make this work will be to increase this limit... do you have any other suggestions for my use case? I don't believe querying the entire collection as an enumerable will work as 120k records is just one set, there will be many others so seems like that's too much data to pull out.

Comment: Also adding 120k records to the collection takes substantially more time than adding a List of 120k records to one key, so I'm worried about that as well