# How to enumerate all partitions and aggregate results

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a multiple partitioned stateful service. How can I enumerate all its partitions and aggregate results, using [service remoting](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting/) for communication between client and service?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can enumerable the partitions using `FabricClient`:

```
var serviceName = new Uri("fabric:/MyApp/MyService");
using (var client = new FabricClient())
{
    var partitions = await client.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(serviceName);

    foreach (var partition in partitions)
    {
        Debug.Assert(partition.PartitionInformation.Kind == ServicePartitionKind.Int64Range);
        var partitionInformation = (Int64RangePartitionInformation)partition.PartitionInformation;
        var proxy = ServiceProxy.Create<IMyService>(serviceName, new ServicePartitionKey(partitionInformation.LowKey));
        // TODO: call service
    }
}
```

Note that you should probably cache the results of `GetPartitionListAsync` since service partitions cannot be changed without recreating the service (you can just keep a list of the `LowKey` values).

In addition, `FabricClient` should also be shared as much as possible (see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.fabricclient.aspx#Anchor_7)).

Comment: Good idea keeping a list of `LowKey` values. Thanks for that.

Comment: What does "sharing" `FabricClient` mean?