# Can't confirm any actors are being created

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, actor

In Service Fabric I am trying to call an ActorService and get a list of all actors. I'm not getting any errors, but no actors are returned. It's always zero.

This is how I add actors :

```
ActorProxy.Create<IUserActor>(
  new ActorId(uniqueName), 
  "fabric:/ECommerce/UserActorService");
```

And this is how I try to get a list of all actors:

```
var proxy = ActorServiceProxy.Create(new Uri("fabric:/ECommerce/UserActorService"), 0);

ContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource().Token;
List<ActorInformation> activeActors = new List<ActorInformation>();

do
{
  var proxy = GetUserActorServiceProxy();
  PagedResult<ActorInformation> page = await proxy.GetActorsAsync(continuationToken, cancellationToken);

  activeActors.AddRange(page.Items.Where(x => x.IsActive));

  continuationToken = page.ContinuationToken;
}
while (continuationToken != null);
```

But no matter how many users I've added, the page object will always have zero items. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument `int` in [ActorServiceProxy.Create(Uri, int, string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.client.actorserviceproxy.create?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Actors_Client_ActorServiceProxy_Create_System_Uri_System_Int64_System_String_) is the partition key (you can find out more about actor partitioning [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform#service-fabric-partition-concepts-for-actors)).

The issue here is that your code checks only **one** partition (`partitionKey = 0`).

So the solutions is quite simple - you have to iterate over all partitions of you service. Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37775841/9497714) with code sample to get partitions and iterate over them.

## UPDATE 2019.07.01

---

I didn't spot this from the first time but the reason why you aren't getting any actors returned is because you aren't creating any actors - you are creating proxies!

The reason for such confusion is that Service Fabric actors are virtual i.e. from the user point of view actor always exists but in real life Service Fabric manages actor object lifetime automatically persisting and restoring it's state as needed.

Here is a quote from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction#actor-lifetime):

> An actor is automatically activated (causing an actor object to be constructed) **the first time a message is sent to its actor ID**. After some period of time, the actor object is garbage collected. In the future, using the actor ID again, causes a new actor object to be constructed. An actor's state outlives the object's lifetime when stored in the state manager.

In you example you've never send any messages to actors!

Here is a code example I wrote in `Program.cs` of newly created Actor project:

```cs
// Please don't forget to replace "fabric:/Application16/Actor1ActorService" with your actor service name.

ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<Actor1> (
  (context, actorType) => 
    new ActorService(context, actorType)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

var actor = ActorProxy.Create<IActor1>(
  ActorId.CreateRandom(),
  new Uri("fabric:/Application16/Actor1ActorService"));

_ = actor.GetCountAsync(default).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

ContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
var activeActors = new List<ActorInformation>();

var serviceName = new Uri("fabric:/Application16/Actor1ActorService");
using (var client = new FabricClient())
{
  var partitions = client.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(serviceName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();;

  foreach (var partition in partitions)
  {
    var pi = (Int64RangePartitionInformation) partition.PartitionInformation;
    var proxy = ActorServiceProxy.Create(new Uri("fabric:/Application16/Actor1ActorService"), pi.LowKey);
    var page = proxy.GetActorsAsync(continuationToken, default).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    activeActors.AddRange(page.Items);

    continuationToken = page.ContinuationToken;
  }
}

Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

Pay special attention to the line:

`_ = actor.GetCountAsync(default).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Here is where the first message to actor is sent.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time! But i cant see how that code can make any difference. First of all i only have one partition. Secondly, it does the same thing for every partition. It uses the low key as a partition key, and that is the same for each partition no?

Comment: Also, i saw in the code you linked that the Create method used IMyService type. Is that nescessary or does it also work with IActorService? Cause my ActorService does not have its own service type yet. 

Anyway, i iterated through the partitions but nothing was returned. Its empty. And i made sure to add three actors before trying to list them.

Comment: OMFG! This is amazing. Of course. So in reality i should think of actors as non persistent. Its only their state that is persistent. so if i dont assig a state to a certain ID then nothing will be saved. And if an ID has a state, then there is metadat saved about that actor. Correct? I will try this tonight.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for teaching me this fundamntal. I will sure post more SF question here during the coming weeks, but now i am ready to start exploring.